Flutter Consumer not notified properly when changing user status
I am using a view called app.dart which consums the AuthProvider and redirects the user based on the "Status"-Field. The view looks like this:
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(
      builder: (context, user, child) {
        switch (user.status) {
          case Status.uninitialized:
            return const InitView();
          case Status.unauthenticated:
            return const Login();
          case Status.authenticated:
            return const LoadView();
          case Status.hasObjects:
            return ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => ObjectProvider(
                  authProvider, authProvider.setStatusFromCallback),
              child: const HomePage(),
            );
          case Status.unpaired:
            return const PairingHome(hasError: false);
          case Status.error:
            return const ServerError();
          default:
            return const InitView();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

This view is called in main.dart. The file looks like this:
// sentry stuff

      appRunner: () => runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
            child: MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>(
                  create: (context) => AuthProvider(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<ObjectProvider>(
                  create: (context) => ObjectProvider(
                    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false),
                    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false)
                        .setStatusFromCallback,
                  ),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
                  create: (context) => UserProvider(
                    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false),
                  ),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider<AppProvider>(
                  create: (context) => AppProvider(
                    Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              child: Main(),
            ),
          )));

class Main extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainState createState() => _MainState();
}

// Create a State class for Main
class _MainState extends State<Main> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: '',
      scaffoldMessengerKey: rootScaffoldMessengerKey,
      initialRoute: '/',
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'GalanoGrotesque'),
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      locale: getLanguage(),
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('de'),
        Locale('en'),
        Locale('fr'),
      ],
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const App(),
        '/login': (context) => const Login(),
        '/home': (context) => const HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

So according to my understandings, the consumer in app.dart should properly redirect the user if the status gets changed, and notifyListeners(); is called. But this only works when the app is first started, so when runApp is initially called. E.g. when logging out in my profile view, the user doesn't get automatically redirected to the Login() even though the status is Status.unauthenticated. But when restarting the app, the redirect works.
Did i forget anything in my code
UPDATE
This only happened when I got to a view that was not in the App-Widget. When I left the widget tree, the auto-update of the views based on the user.status didn't work anymore.

Try

Wrapping your MultiProvider with a Builder

Wrap your MaterialApp with AuthProvider



I think this answer could benefit from a little additional detail and explanation.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
